# Getting SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool when scraping a list of links

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a list of links of a reviews website:

```
links =['https://www.yelp.com/biz/city-tamale-bronx-3',   'https://www.yelp.com/biz/the-boogie-down-grind-caf%C3%A9-bronx', 'https://www.yelp.com/biz/fratillis-pizza-bronx', 'https://www.yelp.com/biz/randall-restaurant-bronx', 'https://www.yelp.com/biz/valencia-bakery-bronx-3', 'https://www.yelp.com/biz/the-point-cafe-and-bascom-catering-new-york', 'https://www.yelp.com/biz/delfini-restaurant-bronx', 'https://www.yelp.com/biz/bayside-seafood-company-bronx', 'https://www.yelp.com/biz/il-forno-bakery-bronx', 'https://www.yelp.com/biz/allen-restaurant-bronx']
```

I wrote a function that retrieves the name of the reviewer:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def getReviewerName (restaurantLink, headers, proxies): 
    session = requests.Session()
    time.sleep(10)
    req = session.get (restaurantLink,headers = headers, proxies =  proxies)     
    bs = BeautifulSoup (req.text, "html.parser")  
    time.sleep(4)
    nameDiv = bs.find_all ("div", {"class":"media-story"})
    time.sleep(3)
    name = [name.find ("li", {"class": "user-name"}) for name in  nameDiv]
    time.sleep(2)
    name = [n.text for n in name if n is not None]
    print (name)
```

I am applying time.sleep before each request so that my bot remains undetected.

I wrote a for loop that applies the function getReviewerName to each link in the list of links:

```
for link in links:
    headers = {'User-Agent': get_User_Agent()}
    proxies = {"http": "http://"+get_proxies(), "https":"http://" +  get_proxies()}
    getReviewerName (link, headers, proxies )
```

In this for loop I am using a function called get_User_Agent() which returns a random User-Agent, I am also using a function called get_proxies() which returns a random proxy. All this with the aim of remaining undetected.

I am getting the expected result just for the first link in the list of links:

```
['\nDavid L.\n', '\nKarla G.\n', '\nMickey W.\n', '\nGabrielle  P.\n', '\nOmar M.\n', '\nフェルナンド\n', '\nMichael B.\n', '\nBrittany H.\n', '\nTy C.\n', '\ndouble double u.\n', '\nLizzy N.\n', '\nAlina G.\n', '\nSam W.\n', '\nCristina C.\n', '\nLetticia C.\n', '\nJennifer S.\n', '\nJeremy R.\n', '\nKahliah L.\n', '\nE. M.\n', '\nSaïeda H.\n']
```

However, when I get to the second link, I am getting an SSLError:

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.yelp.com', port=443): Max  retries exceeded with url: /biz/the-boogie-down-grind-caf%C3%A9-bronx (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))
```

Any help on how to sort this out will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your proxies, you are probably using HTTP proxies as HTTPS i.e. change your proxy format from:

```
{"https": "https://..."}
```

to

```
{"http": "http://..."}
```